# An attempt of solving the tangent map of left multiplication by $g$ on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is also a left multiplication

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

[image]

This problem is from "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu.

I think I understand the solution, but I would like to ask if the following idea of approaching it is right.

When I dealt with this problem, I tried this way.
Suppose $X_{I} \in T_{I}(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$ and then we have $$\begin{align*}
d(lg)_{I}(X_{I}) \in   T_{g}(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))
\end{align*}$$ Then, since $lg$ is a global diffeomorphism on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
d(lg)_{I}(X_{I}) = (lg_{*}X)_{g}
\end{align*}$$ That is, the $X_{I}$ after the tangent map is just the pushforward of $X$ at $g$ . Then suppose $X_{I}$ has integral curve $\gamma$ , then $d(lg)_{I}(X_{I})$ should have integral curve $lg \circ \gamma$ which is $g \gamma$

The problem asks me to prove $$\begin{align*}
gX_{I}= d(lg)_{I}(X_{I})
\end{align*}$$Thus I considered to evaluate them at the same smooth function $f$ $$\begin{align*}
gX_{I}(f)  &=  g \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} (f \circ  \gamma) (t)
\\ &=  g \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t))
\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
d(lg)_{I}(X_{I})(f)&=  X_{I}(f \circ  lg)
\\ &=  \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} f(g \gamma(t))
\end{align*}$$ Then I got stuck here. I think probably something goes wrong with my attempt. Any help on this? Thanks!

Comment: You’re over complicating things by using the derivations at a point definition of the tangent space. Note that $GL_n$ is an open submanifold of Euclidean space, so you really really don’t have to use that definition at all.

Comment: Hint: The left multiplication is a linear map on the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices. What is the derivative of a linear map? You probably learned this in your vector calculus class.